# Unintended auto-scroll

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a problem where the page is autoscrolling further down after an intended scroll. How can i fix this?

Code:

```
if ($(selector).attr('just_created') == '1')
{
    $("#category").focus(); // #category is an input field
    $(selector).attr('just_created','');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#categories").offset().top}, 300); //#categories is a panel div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL. I am stupid. It was not autoscrolling by itself... It was my "Created successfully" message that was pushing it down and up as it was showing and hiding... Sorry XD